# Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" code: "3

Tags: jquery, grid-layout

Hey, it's me again with a question about jquery and that [gridlayout](http://phase-change.org/jquery.gridlayout/) I made a php template with switch and the code i am inserting is this

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="grid">
<div class="box"><img src="img/an_005_BUR_thebeat.jpg" width="310px" height="438px" />3 index</div>
<div class="box"><img src="img/an_014_GUE_homme_a.jpg" width="310px" height="404px" />4 Culture</div>
<div class="box"><img src="img/an_044_BVL_springmotiv.jpg" width="310px" height="310px" />5 Pharma</div>
<div class="box"><img src="img/an_039_AN_diskette.jpg" width="310px" height="465px" />6 Pharma IT</div>
<div class="box"><img width="310px" height="100px" />7 Culture</div>
<div class="box"><img width="310px" height="120px" />8 Cosmetics</div>
<div class="box"><img width="310px" height="400px" />9 IT</div>
<div class="box"><img width="310px" height="400px" />10 Culture</div>
<div class="box"><img width="310px" height="400px" />11 IT</div>
<div class="box"><img width="310px" height="400px" />12 Culture</div>
</div>

</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#grid').gridLayout('.box', {col_width: 340, min_cols: 2});
        // options - (values above are the defaults)
        // col_width: the width of each grid block
        // min_cols: the minimum number of cols on the page (reducing browser width below this will not decrease number of columns). Set to your largest block (3 = block spans 3 columns)

        // gridLayout.placeAtEnd() - for placing a block at bottom right of grid
        var final_block = $('');
        $('#grid').gridLayout.placeAtEnd( final_block );

        // gridchange event fires when window resize forces a grid refresh
        $('#grid').bind( "gridchange", function(e){
            console.log('gridchange event fired');
            // reposition the final block
            $('#grid').gridLayout.placeAtEnd( final_block );
        });

        // this forces a redraw of grid
        $('body').gridLayout.refresh();

        // returns heights of each column
        console.log( 'gridLayout.info():', $('#grid').gridLayout.info() );
    });

</script>
```

The jquery script and the plugin are loaded in the header. When i try to run this. Firebug tells me:

"Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" code: "3"

Do anybody know how to fix this?

Here is an example i loaded up: http://18735.webhosting7.1blu.de/neu/index.php?item=lifestyle

Comment: At which line is this error showing up?

Comment: the full markup would help. The error means you (the plugin) are trying to insert a node into an invalid parent e.g a td onto a table.

Comment: or mock up a demo with the issue at jsbin.com

Comment: i uploaded the whole thing to my webspace
http://18735.webhosting7.1blu.de/neu/index.php?item=lifestyle

Comment: The error occurs at  

fragment.appendChild( ret[i] );
jquery-1.3.2.js (line 957)

Comment: And this is the part wich is not correctly working

 // gridchange event fires when window resize forces a grid refresh
  $('#grid').bind( "gridchange", function(e){
  console.log('gridchange event fired');
   // reposition the final block
   $('#grid').gridLayout.placeAtEnd( final_block );
  
  });

i checked it through firebug and the function before is logged and the function after also. but this one just gets jumped over...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am pretty sure your error is with the following. What is $('') !

```
var final_block = $('');
$('#grid').gridLayout.placeAtEnd( final_block );
```

It works if I say

```
var final_block = $('<div />');
$('#grid').gridLayout.placeAtEnd( final_block );
```

Comment: No this is not the error. In this variable you can place a div, wich u want tp appear last. I just left it empty because i didnt need it..

Comment: You're right, the errors is gone. But still the grid is not being arranged. It just puts on div under another.

Comment: cool, question answered then :) I would ask another question for your next issue. It will then help others who have the same issue rather than the answer being held under this question (hard to find via google etc)

Answer (score 4):

The error message is displayed (in firebug) if you have incorrect html in a $() constructor, as well as when you try to append a node to itself, e.g.:

```
$div = $('<div />');
$div.append($div);
```