# insert html content inside a class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to insert html content like,

```
$.get("_html/saveme.html", function(data){
    $(".saveWin .modalCSS").html(data); //Error here
});
```

In Firefox it is giving me error as,

```
Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy
```

In IE it is working fine.
Please suggest me, are there any other ways to call class inside a class and insert html content.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to insert the HTML into (at least) two possible elements with the dual class search in the jQuery.

What does your HTML look like?

Comment: some html and markuyp where your container placed needed

Comment: It looks like element wasn't found with such selector `".saveWin .modalCSS"`. The same issue was asked already and the problem was - no element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119211/node-cannot-be-inserted-at-the-specified-point-in-the-hierarchy-code-3

Comment: What exactly is `data`?  If it's a whole web page, then you probably can't insert that into the middle of an existing web page.  You would need only valid tags that go within the body?

Comment: In data, I have the li tags. I alerted it and got data as [object XMLDocument] in firefox but in IE getting the complete html content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just found the answer...

Instead of calling like,

```
$.get("_html/saveme.html", function(data){
    $(".saveWin .modalCSS").html(data); //Error here
});
```

If I call,

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "_html/saveme.html",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
    $(".saveWin .modalCSS").html(data);
    }
});
```

This works. 
Thanks a lot for your time guys.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot be sure what the issue is exactly coz I don't have enough details.

But I can tell you how to figure it out: Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Add these statements in your Ajax callback:

```
console.log( $(".saveWin .modalCSS") );
console.log(data);
```

Check if `$('.saveWin .modalCSS')` is turning up any results. See what the value of `data` is.

Since it works in IE, there is something peculiar going on. Use Firebug to debug the problem.

Cheers :)

Comment: If I alert the data I am getting the HTMl content in IE. In firefox it is showing me [object XMLDocument].

Comment: ah! so its a MIME-type issue - watch that request in firebug and in the Net/console tab, find the MIME-type on the response for you ajax call. Jquery can ask for a particular mime type, and you should set it to `text/plain`.